# mirror and control ipad screen from ubuntu

Tags: ipad, ios

Hi I will like to mirror and control ipad screen from ubuntu 18.04?
Found solutions for android but none so far for ipad or ios, please help!

Comment: It's a good question, but unrelated to Ubuntu.  Apple has a very tight set of controls over their ecosystem.  You'll have to use an application like TeamViewer that is available to iOS device users.  The Desktop client for TeamViewer is available for Linux/Ubuntu as well, so could solve the issue.

Comment: Hi ThatGuy, it seems even teamviewer IOS client is not able to control the ipad screen....  isn't there any way by which we can get ios controlled from ubuntu?

Comment: @Shumi08 - Unfortunately, you may have to go back to Apple.  I'm fairly certain there aren't any options to control iOS devices from most platforms apart from MacOS (there may be a few options from Windows, but I don't know of any off hand).